# How to include a double quote in a C macro defintion?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have the following test program:

```
#define q "

int main() {
    printf(q hello world q);
}
```

Compiling this with gcc (I've tried both versions 12.3 and 11.4 on Ubuntu) produces this error:
`error: missing terminating " character` on line 1. Compiling with clang (Apple clang version 11.0.0) produces the error `error: expected expression` on line 4.

Now, I had always assumed that, when a C program was compiled, the preprocessor ran first, handled all of the preprocessor directives, and then the output of the preprocessor was read by the complier proper.

Running this test program through the gcc preprocessor (gcc -E) produces a warning, but no errors, and yields this sensible output:

```
int main() {
    printf(" hello world ");
}
```

This program will now compile without errors and runs just fine.  So, while I can't compile the original program directly, if I run the preprocessor manually and compile the result, then it works.  This violates my (apparently mistaken) understanding of how the preprocessor and the compiler operate together.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to include a double quote character (but not two of them) in the definition of a C macro?
2. What is happening with the preprocessor and compiler in this example that allows it to compile and run if I run the preprocessor manually, but not when the preprocessor is run automatically as part of the compilation process?

Comment: You can't do this. The preprocessor operates at the token level, not character level. String literals are a single token.

Comment: Maybe the original C compiler worked the way you thought, but modern C compilers don't. The preprocessor is integrated into the parser, it's not a separate pass that produces text source for the next pass. So the output of `gcc -E` will be misleading.

Comment: Maybe not what you want but you can do: `#define q(x) #x` and then: `printf(q(hello world));`

Comment: [preprocessing is at phase 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C preprocessor deals with tokens (and token sequences), not individual characters, and tokenization happens before preprocessing.  That means you can't manipulate things in the preprocessor that are not tokens -- and a bare `"` is not a token, it is part of a string literal token.

You might be able to do something more like what you want by using a more general macro processor like [m4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language))